# How do I join huge csv files (1000's of columns x 1000's rows) efficiently using C/C++?

Tags: c++, join, csv, rows

I have several (1-5) very wide (~50,000 columns) .csv files.  The files are (.5GB-1GB) in size (avg. size around 500MB).  I need to perform a join on the files on a pre-specified column.  Efficiency is, of course, the key.  Any solutions that can be scaled out to efficiently allow multiple join columns is a bonus, though not currently required.  Here are my inputs:

-Primary File

-Secondary File(s)

-Join column of Primary File (name or col. position)

-Join column of Secondary File (name or col. position)

-Left Join or Inner Join?

Output = 1 File with results of the multi-file join

I am looking to solve the problem using a C-based language, but of course an algorithmic solution would also be very helpful.

Comment: "Yikes" is all I can contribute to this one...

Comment: There is a C++ implementation doing this already: http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ the source is available for download.

Comment: If your CSVs are simple (no quoting, no commas inside) and you're in Linux world, you can probably get by with cut, paste and sort - no need to write C code.

Comment: @Cheesebaron nice!  That looks like a handy tool.

Comment: Sounds like a good application for a database, especially the Left join part.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a good reason not to use a database (for all I know, the 50,000 columns may constitute such a reason), you probably have no choice but to clench your teeth and build yourself an index for the right file. Read through it sequentially to populate a hash table where each entry contains just the key column and an offset in the file where the entire row begins. The index itself then ought to fit comfortably in memory, and if you have enough address space (i.e. unless you're stuck with 32-bit addressing) you should memory-map the actual file data so you can access and output the appropriate right rows easily as you walk sequentially through the *left* file.

Comment: I am, in fact, going to be doing this on a 32-bit architecture.  My users cannot be expected to have more than 32-bit or more than 2GB of total RAM.  I think you are right about having to memory-map each file, as I could have more than two files on which to perform the join/merge.  You think I could still run out of address space?...isn't that the point of memory-mapping?

Comment: Not sure how not running out of addresses would be the point of mmapping. If you're mapping 5 GB there are simply not enough bits in a 32-bit address to tell which byte of which file you want to access. On a 32-bit architecture you'll typically only have 2 GB of userspace addresses, which is subject to some fragmenting from things that are already mapped _before_ you request the mmap. So I'd say it's a toss-up whether you will be able to mmap even one 1 GB file. You can still have the index in memory, but you'll have to seek back & forth in the file to retrieve the records.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet by far is something like Sqlite, there's C++ bindings for it and it's tailor made for lighting fast inserts and queries.

For the actual reading of the data, you can just go row by row and insert the fields in Sqlite, no need for cache-destroying objects of objects :) As an optimization, you should group up multiple inserts in one statement (`insert into table(...) select ... union all select ... union all select ...`).

Comment: If you're going with SQLite, be aware `SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN` is 2000 by default so you may run into issues with ~50k columns. It can be set at compile time to a max of 32,767 columns. See https://sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use C or C++, open the file and load the file directly into a database such as MySQL.  The C and C++ languages do not have adequate data table structures nor functionality for manipulating the data.  A spreadsheet application may be useful, but may not be able to handle the capacities.

That said, I recommend objects for each field (column).  Define a record (file specific) as a collection of fields.  Read a text line from a file into a string.  Let the record load the field data from the string.  Store records into a `vector`.

Create a new record for the destination file.  For each record from the input file(s), load the new record using those fields.  Finally, for each record, print the contents of each field with separation characters.

An alternative is to whip up a 2 dimensional matrix of strings.

Your performance bottleneck will be I/O.  You may want to read huge blocks of data in.  The thorn to the efficiency is the variable record length of a CSV file.

I still recommend using a database.  There are plenty of free ones out there, such as MySQl.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "join". Are the columns in file 1 the same as in file 2? If so, you just need a merge sort. Most likely a solution based on merge sort is "best". But I agree with @Blindy above that you should use an existing tool like Sqlite. Such a solution is probably more future proof against changes to the column lists.